# Function Returns Incorrect Value

Tags: functions, numerics

I have the following definition for a function

`Funct[b_, ci_, cf_, w_] := 
  Integrate[(c - w)*Exp[-b*(c - w)^2], {c, ci, cf}];`

The function returns a  value of zero for inputs : Funct[2.3,2,3,4];

The function expression for Funct[2.3,3,4,wa] is:
`-0.217391 2.71828^(-2.3 (-3. + wa)^2) + 
 0.217391 2.71828^(-2.3 (-2. + wa)^2)`

The above function is clearly not zero for wa = 4;

However, mathematica returns a 0 value for me. I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.? Any suggestions?

`In[16]:= Funct[b_, ci_, cf_, w_] := 
  Integrate[(c - w)*Exp[-b*(c - w)^2], {c, ci, cf}];
Funct[be, ci, cf, w]`

`Out[17]= (E^(-be (cf^2 + ci^2 + w^2)) (-E^(be (ci^2 + 2 cf w)) + E^(
   be (cf^2 + 2 ci w))))/(2 be)`

`In[19]:= Funct[2.3, 2, 3, 4]
Exp[-2.3*(9 + 4 + 16)]*(-Exp[2.3*(4 + 24)] + Exp[2.3*(3 + 16)])/2/2.3`

`Out[19]= 0.`

`Out[20]= -0.0217954`

`In[38]:= X[w_] := Funct[2.3, 2.0, 3.0, w]`

`In[39]:= X[wa]`

`Out[39]= -0.217391 2.71828^(-2.3 (-3. + wa)^2) + 
 0.217391 2.71828^(-2.3 (-2. + wa)^2)`

`In[51]:= X[4]`

`Out[51]= 0.`

Comment: You have been bitten by floating point numbers. Try doing the integral with exact numbers and then converting the result to floating point. N[Funct[23/10, 2, 3, 4]]

Comment: Alternatively, replace the `:=` in the definition of `X` by `=`.

Comment: @marmot Your suggestion worked. Thanks. I dont know why a delayed assignment is causing this problem?

Answer (score 3):

It is floating point issue

```
Funct[b_, ci_, cf_, w_] := 
 Integrate[(c - w)*Exp[-Rationalize@b*(c - w)^2], {c, ci, cf}]
Funct[2.3, 2, 3, 4] 
%//N
-0.021773
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, the question is, should this have happened in the first place? I do not understand Mathematica floating point system well. But I tried this in Maple. Here is side by side

**Mathematica**

```
   Integrate[(c - 4)*Exp[-2.3*(c - 4)^2], {c, 2, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Maple**

```
   int((c - 4)*exp(-2.3*(c - 4)^2), c=2..3);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

why did Mathematica give zero when using `2.3` vs. `23/10` and Maple did not?
Clearly the difference is due to how Mathematica handled floating point. But how did this exactly resulted in the difference shown?

Someone who knows more about Mathematica internal floating point handling can answer this part.

**Update:**
To answer the comment above

> I dont know why a delayed assignment is causing this problem?

When you write

```
Funct[b_, ci_, cf_, w_] := Integrate[(c - w)*Exp[-b*(c - w)^2], {c, ci, cf}]
```

Then the integration will happen when you make the call to `Funct`, using as input the parameters passed in. But when you type

```
Funct[b_, ci_, cf_, w_] = Integrate[(c - w)*Exp[-b*(c - w)^2], {c, ci, cf}]
```

Then `Integrate` will get evaluated immediately and the result of the integration (the anti-derivative) is what get evaluated when you make the call to `Funct`

This make a **HUGE** difference. In the case of immediate evaluation `=`, the integration result is symbolic, and it is

```
 Integrate[(c-w)*Exp[-b*(c-w)^2],{c,ci,cf}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And it is the above which is now evaluated when you make the call

```
  %/.{w->4,ci->2,cf->3,b->2.3}
  -0.021773
```

With the delayed case `:=`, the following is what gets evaluated

```
  Integrate[(c-4)*Exp[-2.3*(c-4)^2],{c,2,3}]
  0.
```

He reason for the difference in answer, is that Integrate went though different code path. In the case of `=`, symbols were used and it might used different logic, in the case of `:=` floating points used, and it went though different code path? or using different integration method.  Either way, the answer of 0. is clearly not correct. But I am not an expert of this, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When Mathematica can integrate the expression symbolically it can be useful to go that route.

```
Integrate[(c - w)*Exp[-b*(c - w)^2], {c, ci, cf}]

(* (E^(-b (cf^2 + ci^2 + w^2)) (-E^(b (ci^2 + 2 cf w)) + 
    E^(b (cf^2 + 2 ci w))))/(2 b) *)
```

So now we define

```
fun[b_, ci_, cf_, w_] := (E^(-b (cf^2 + ci^2 + w^2)) (-E^(b (ci^2 + 2 cf w))
                         + E^(b (cf^2 + 2 ci w))))/(2 b)
```

Test it with the numbers that produced a problem

```
fun[2.3, 3, 4, 4]

(* -0.195596 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug of the definite integral, since the indefinite integration works quite well (Using MMA version 8.0)

```
    int1[b_, c_, w_] := Integrate[(c - w) Exp[-b*(c - w)^2], c]

    int1[2.3, c, 4]

    (*   -0.217391 2.71828^(-2.3 (-4. + c)^2)   *)

    (int1[2.3, c, 4] /. c -> 3) - (int1[2.3, c, 4] /. c -> 2)

    (*   -0.0217734     *)
```